# Can react native inject gatsbyjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gatsby

I have an gatsbyjs website, how can react native inject gatsbyjs and pass data to gatsbyjs?

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to inject GatsbyJs is using a Webview in RN. You can use this library https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview, you can easily pass data through query string.